# Is there a way to create groups of contacts?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts, motorola-droid

On my old Nokia phone I was able to create groups of contacts. I found this very useful and had groups such as Co-workers, Neighbors, Doctors, Friends, Family, etc.

Is there a way to do this on my Moto Droid? The only way I've found to group contacts so far is to mark them as Favorites, or create custom folders with direct contact shortcuts on my home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sunpech is correct about that. However, it doesn't quite work in the way you are envisioning it. Your groups in your Google contacts don't sort your contacts in your phone, instead you are simply able to specify to Android which of those groups you want synced. When you are in your contact list (in Android) you can hit Menu and go to "Display options" and choose your preferences there. The actual appearance of the "Display options" screen will vary depending on your version of Android, but ultimately, you will be able to choose which groups to include in your contacts, and even specify to only display those with phone numbers.

I hope this clears things up for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do that on the Android device directly.  But you can create groups within your contacts in Gmail, and it will sync down to your device.

Comment: I have my Gmail contacts organized into some groups, but I don't see them in my contacts list on my phone. Where do the groups show up?

Answer (score 0):

Matt, Contacts GroupU is a free app that let's you create groups and sync w/ gmail groups. I stopped using it months ago because it turned out seperating my contacts wasn't that impoertant to me afterall. I do recall that it was a little quirky at first which caused some duplicate groups. Play around with it and figure out the difference between groupU groups and synced groups before you spend time getting things organized.

Comment: I was going to check this out, but there were enough negative comments from people having issues that were serious enough that I didn't think it would be worth the risk. Thanks for the suggestion though!