# How can I send an SMS message to a group?

Tags: sms

I want to send an SMS message to a group of people either in a contact group or maybe selected from a list of contacts.

How can I do that?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/a-good-bulk-sms-app and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/with-the-google-voice-app-is-it-possible-to-send-an-sms-to-multiple-people

Comment: And this for a couple ways to create a contact group: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/is-there-a-way-to-create-groups-of-contacts

Comment: I would recommend the carrier group message option which can help you by reducing the group SMS cost

Answer (score 5):

Since things vary slightly from UI to UI, this may depend on which phone you have.  For instance, on Stock Droid X (Motoblur) I believe that if you are composing a message, hitting the Menu key will provide the "Add recipient" option.  On Liberty ROM 2 on Droid X, using the stock messaging client, you can simply add users in a message "To" field by separating them with commas.

Answer (score 3):

[Handcent SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) allows you to choose multiple users or a previously defined contact group.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend getting the SMS app hello sms because it is the only third party app I'm aware of that deals with both group messages and sending pictures well. The crucial aspect from a group texting perspective is not just sending the message to a group but also making sure people can reply to the group... On the sms app on my Samsung note II, for example, I could send a group message but if someone responded, it would only go to me and would show up as a conversation just between me and the responder.

I had to test a bunch of third party sms apps when I got my nexus 5 because it only took about five seconds for me to realize I hated using hangouts for texting. I used hand cent for awhile but I didn't like the UI at all... I can't remember whether it had both group texting and picture sending, but I think it did. Anyway I switched to hello and I am happy to report that it handles group texting and picture sending like a champ. I recommend getting a scrollable SMS widget for your home screen that has compose new message and reply buttons on it. Happy texting!

Answer (score 1):

The "Hangout" app will still handle multiple sms sending, and I have found it maintained previously setup groups, but during a recent update it stopped allowing you to setup group conversations; only allowing you to do so with "Group conversation by MMS" checked, which obviously costs money as I don't get those included in my monthly bill.

So I found you can trick the system...

1. in SMS Settings > Check Group conversation by MMS (I have never found this to work anyway)
2. Create your group, as you start adding "anyone else?" you will see the message type switch from SMS to MMS.
3. in SMS Settings > Uncheck Group Conversations.

You will retain the conversation you just created, but the send type will show as SMS.

If you want to add more people or setup other bulk sending you will need to repeat the steps above.

I know it is a faff, but it does work.

Comment: For some reason I don't always see the "anyone else?" option.

Comment: have you definitely checked Group Messaging? before creating a group? I thought it was called Group Conversations, but maybe it changed in Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you are creating a new message, when you are adding a recipient you can normally add more than one person, thus sending that one message to a group of people. The method of sending one message to multiple people however varies from phone to phone so unless I know what phone specifically you have then I can only give you what most phones are capable of doing regarding to sending a message to a group of people.

Answer (score 0):

You can try GoSMS app which is very user friendly and you could directly send SMSs to groups directly (groups can be created easily)